# TableView automatic calculation of values after commit

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, calculator

I have a problem until I found but not working as expected ...

is the following I have a tableview with the following columns AV1 | AV2 | AV3 | AV4 | SUM
I want that after entering a new value in any cell the SUM column automatically update with the column sums AV1: AV4
example:

after changing any value in columns AV1: AV4, the column sum to automatically update its value

`| AV1  | AV2   | AV3   | AV4   | SUM   |
 |----- |-----  |-----  |-----  |-----  |
 | 5    | 5     | 5     | 5     | 20    |
 | 1    | 2     | 3     | 4     | 10    |
 | 3    | 7     | 10    | 5     | 25    |`

my code:

```
 col_av4.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Notas, BigDecimal> param) -> new EditingCellNotas());
    col_av4.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Notas, BigDecimal> t) -> {
        t.getRowValue().setMediaFinal(t.getNewValue());
        t.getRowValue().setMediaGeral(media());
    });

 private BigDecimal media() {
    BigDecimal media = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal av1, av2, av3, av4;
    av1 = tbl_notas.selectionModelProperty().getValue().getSelectedItem().getAv1();
    System.out.println("AV1" + av1);
    av2 = tbl_notas.selectionModelProperty().getValue().getSelectedItem().getAv2();
    System.out.println("AV2" + av2);
    av3 = tbl_notas.selectionModelProperty().getValue().getSelectedItem().getAv3();
    System.out.println("AV3" + av3);
    av4 = tbl_notas.selectionModelProperty().getValue().getSelectedItem().getAv4();
    System.out.println("AV4" + av4);
    try {
        media = (av1.add(av2).add(av3).add(av4)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(4));

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return media;
}
```

this code works but I need to double-click in the column cell sum 
for the new value to update

**UPDATE CLASS**

**I followed this example https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453**
**now how to bind values ​​following the example given in response?**

This is my class notes, I changed the attributes for a double.

```
package com.group.sisgefx.model;
// Generated 09/07/2014 20:05:25 by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0

 import java.math.MathContext;
 import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
 import javax.persistence.Access;
 import javax.persistence.AccessType;
 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.FetchType;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 /**
 * Notas generated by hbm2java
 */
 @Entity
 @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
 @Table(name = "notas", catalog = "sisge")
 public class Notas implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final MathContext mc = new MathContext(4);

private IntegerProperty _codNota;
private DoubleProperty _av1;
private IntegerProperty _faltas1;
private DoubleProperty _av2;
private IntegerProperty _faltas2;
private DoubleProperty _av3;
private IntegerProperty _faltas3;
private DoubleProperty _av4;
private IntegerProperty _faltas4;
private DoubleProperty _exame;
private DoubleProperty _mediaGeral;
private DoubleProperty _mediaFinal;
private StringProperty _resultado;
private IntegerProperty _totalFaltas;

private Integer codNota;
private Disciplinas disciplinas;
private Aluno aluno;
private Turma turma;
private Double av1;
private Integer faltas1;
private Double av2;
private Integer faltas2;
private Double av3;
private Integer faltas3;
private Double av4;
private Integer faltas4;
private Double exame;
private Double mediaGeral;
private Double mediaFinal;
private String resultado;
private Integer totalFaltas;

public Notas() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cod_nota", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getCodNota() {
    if (_codNota == null) {
        return this.codNota;
    } else {
        return _codNota.get();
    }
}

public void setCodNota(Integer codNota) {
    if (_codNota == null) {
        this.codNota = codNota;
    } else {
        this._codNota.set(codNota);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _codNotaProperty() {
    if (_codNota == null) {
        _codNota = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "codNota", codNota);
    }
    return _codNota;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idDisciplina", nullable = false)
public Disciplinas getDisciplinas() {
    return this.disciplinas;
}

public void setDisciplinas(Disciplinas disciplinas) {
    this.disciplinas = disciplinas;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "matricula", nullable = false)
public Aluno getAluno() {
    return this.aluno;
}

public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idTurma", nullable = false)
public Turma getTurma() {
    return this.turma;
}

public void setTurma(Turma turma) {
    this.turma = turma;
}

@Column(name = "av1", precision = 4)
public Double getAv1() {
    if (_av1 == null) {
        return this.av1;
    } else {
        return _av1.get();
    }
}

public void setAv1(Double av1) {
    if (this._av1 == null) {
        this.av1 = av1;
    } else {
        this._av1.set(av1);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _av1Property() {
    if (_av1 == null) {
        _av1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "av1", av1);
    }
    return _av1;
}

@Column(name = "faltas_1")
public Integer getFaltas1() {
    if (_faltas1 == null) {
        return this.faltas1;
    } else {
        return _faltas1.get();
    }
}

public void setFaltas1(Integer faltas1) {
    if (this._faltas1 == null) {
        this.faltas1 = faltas1;
    } else {
        this._faltas1.set(faltas1);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _faltas1Property() {
    if (_faltas1 == null) {
        _faltas1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "faltas1", faltas1);
    }
    return _faltas1;
}

@Column(name = "av2", precision = 4)
public Double getAv2() {
    if (_av2 == null) {
        return this.av2;
    } else {
        return _av2.get();
    }
}

public void setAv2(Double av2) {
    if (this._av2 == null) {
        this.av2 = av2;
    } else {
        this._av2.set(av2);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _av2Property() {
    if (_av2 == null) {
        _av2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "av2", av2);
    }
    return _av2;
}

@Column(name = "faltas_2")
public Integer getFaltas2() {
    if (_faltas2 == null) {
        return this.faltas2;
    } else {
        return _faltas2.get();
    }
}

public void setFaltas2(Integer faltas2) {
    if (this._faltas2 == null) {
        this.faltas2 = faltas2;
    } else {
        this._faltas2.set(faltas2);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _faltas2Property() {
    if (_faltas2 == null) {
        _faltas2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "faltas2", faltas2);
    }
    return _faltas2;
}

@Column(name = "av3", precision = 4)
public Double getAv3() {
    if (_av3 == null) {
        return this.av3;
    } else {
        return _av3.get();
    }
}

public void setAv3(Double av3) {
    if (this._av3 == null) {
        this.av3 = av3;
    } else {
        this._av3.set(av3);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _av3Property() {
    if (_av3 == null) {
        _av3 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "av3", av3);
    }
    return _av3;
}

@Column(name = "faltas3")
public Integer getFaltas3() {
    if (_faltas3 == null) {
        return this.faltas3;
    } else {
        return _faltas3.get();
    }
}

public void setFaltas3(Integer faltas3) {
    if (this._faltas3 == null) {
        this.faltas3 = faltas3;
    } else {
        this._faltas3.set(faltas3);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _faltas3Property() {
    if (_faltas3 == null) {
        _faltas3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "faltas3", faltas3);
    }
    return _faltas3;
}

@Column(name = "av4", precision = 4)
public Double getAv4() {
    if (_av4 == null) {
        return this.av4;
    } else {
        return _av4.get();
    }
}

public void setAv4(Double av4) {
    if (this._av4 == null) {
        this.av4 = av4;
    } else {
        this._av4.set(av4);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _av4Property() {
    if (_av4 == null) {
        _av4 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "av4", av4);
    }
    return _av4;
}

@Column(name = "faltas_4")
public Integer getFaltas4() {
    if (_faltas4 == null) {
        return this.faltas3;
    } else {
        return _faltas4.get();
    }
}

public void setFaltas4(Integer faltas4) {
    if (this._faltas4 == null) {
        this.faltas4 = faltas4;
    } else {
        this._faltas4.set(faltas4);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _faltas4Property() {
    if (_faltas4 == null) {
        _faltas4 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "faltas4", faltas4);
    }
    return _faltas4;
}

@Column(name = "exame", precision = 4)
public Double getExame() {
    if (_exame == null) {
        return this.exame;
    } else {
        return _exame.get();
    }
}

public void setExame(Double exame) {
    if (this._exame == null) {
        this.exame = exame;
    } else {
        this._av1.set(exame);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _exameProperty() {
    if (_exame == null) {
        _exame = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "exame", exame);
    }
    return _exame;
}

@Column(name = "media_geral", precision = 4)
public Double getMediaGeral() {
    if (_mediaGeral == null) {
        return this.mediaGeral;
    } else {
        return _mediaGeral.get();
    }
}

public void setMediaGeral(Double mediaGeral) {
    if (this._mediaGeral == null) {
        this.mediaGeral = mediaGeral;
    } else {
        this._mediaGeral.set(mediaGeral);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _mediaGeralProperty() {
    if (_mediaGeral == null) {
        _mediaGeral = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "mediaGeral", mediaGeral);
    }
    return _mediaGeral;
}

@Column(name = "mediaFinal", precision = 4)
public Double getMediaFinal() {
    if (_mediaFinal == null) {
        return this.mediaFinal;
    } else {
        return _mediaFinal.get();
    }
}

public void setMediaFinal(Double mediaFinal) {
    if (this._mediaFinal == null) {
        this.mediaFinal = mediaFinal;
    } else {
        this._mediaFinal.set(mediaFinal);
    }
}

//get Property
public DoubleProperty _mediaFinalProperty() {

    if (_mediaFinal == null) {
        _mediaFinal = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "mediaFinal", mediaFinal);
    }
    return _mediaFinal;
}

@Column(name = "resultado", length = 11)
public String getResultado() {
    if (_resultado == null) {
        return this.resultado;
    } else {
        return _resultado.get();
    }
}

public void setResultado(String resultado) {
    if (this._resultado == null) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    } else {
        this._resultado.set(resultado);
    }
}

//get Property
public StringProperty _resultadoProperty() {
    if (_resultado == null) {
        _resultado = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "resultado", resultado);
    }
    return _resultado;
}

@Column(name = "total_faltas")
public Integer getTotalFaltas() {
    if (_totalFaltas == null) {
        return this.totalFaltas;
    } else {
        return _totalFaltas.get();
    }
}

public void setTotalFaltas(Integer totalFaltas) {
    if (this._totalFaltas == null) {
        this.totalFaltas = totalFaltas;
    } else {
        this._totalFaltas.set(totalFaltas);
    }
}

//get Property
public IntegerProperty _totalFaltasProperty() {
    if (_totalFaltas == null) {
        _totalFaltas = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "resultado", totalFaltas);
    }
    return _totalFaltas;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have `mediaGeralProperty()` accessor in your `Notas` class?

Comment: I can not give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your Notas class.  You can bind the value of media (or mediaGeral??) to the sum in the class.  That way all changes will update right away.  It is a bit different to bind BigDecimal because you have to make an ObjectBinding.  Here's an example

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class BigDecTable extends Application {
    private static final MathContext mc = new MathContext(5);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Data(new BigDecimal(123.45,mc),new BigDecimal(123.45,mc)),
                new Data(new BigDecimal(123.45,mc),new BigDecimal(123.45,mc))
        );
        TableView tv = new TableView(data);
        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        StringConverter bdsc = new StringConverter<BigDecimal>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(BigDecimal object) {
                return object.toPlainString();
            }

            @Override
            public BigDecimal fromString(String string) {
                if(string==null || string.isEmpty()) return BigDecimal.ZERO;
                return new BigDecimal(string,mc);
            }
        };

        TableColumn fld1Col = new TableColumn("fld1");
        fld1Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fld1"));
        fld1Col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(bdsc));

        TableColumn fld2Col = new TableColumn("fld2");
        fld2Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fld2"));
        fld2Col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(bdsc));

        TableColumn fld3Col = new TableColumn("tot");
        fld3Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fld3"));
        fld3Col.setEditable(false);

        tv.getColumns().addAll(fld1Col,fld2Col,fld3Col);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tv);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class Data{
        SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld1;
        SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld2;
        SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld3;

        public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld1Property() {return fld1;}
        public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld2Property() {return fld2;}
        public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> fld3Property() {return fld3;}

        public Data(BigDecimal fld1val, BigDecimal fld2val) {
            this.fld1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fld1val);
            this.fld2 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fld2val);
            this.fld3 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(fld2val.add(fld1val));
            fld3.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
                    fld1.get().add(fld2.get(),mc), fld1,fld2));
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you don't use properties then you can can't do automatic updating.  Since your Notas class seems auto-generated I would just update in the onEditCommit().  You can refresh the table by hiding and showing the mediaGeral column (or any column);

```
    table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
    table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```

It's not updating since there's no listener in the table.  If you just add a SimpleDoubleProperty to the Notas class, then it will work but you'll still need the media() method for calculation.

```
public class Notas implements java.io.Serializable {
    transient private SimpleDoubleProperty average;
    //note that this won't serialize so you'd have to create it in readObject()

    ...
    //in the constructor
    this.mediaGeral = mediaGeral;
    average = new SimpleDoubleProperty(mediaGeral);
    ...   
    //make a accessor for the property
    public SimpleDoubleProperty averageProperty(){
        return average;
    }
}
```

Then make a TableColumn using PropertyValueFactory("average")

Edit2:
To bind _mediaGeral use

```
_mediaGeral.bind(_av1.add(_av2.add(_av3.add(_av4.add))).divide(4));
```

in the constructor of the notas class.  You can't have a setter since you're not allowed to set a bound property.

Comment: Posted the class notes, the overall average will be calculated as follows 
`(+ AV1 + AV2 AV3 AV4 +) / 4`

Comment: Thank you, still can not get the automatic update, I study on 
the SimpleDoubleProperty to implement in my application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code will work if you just do the setVisible(false) then true part that I added.  It's still better to use properties if you don't need to use the auto generated code.

Comment: the problem is that my pojo and automatically generated because the database already exists 
has the possibility to use properties with JPA annotations?

Comment: I updated my Nota class properties added in tableview now how to bind the columns (AV1: AV4) with the sum column? using the media() method is updating automatically, but I do not want to have to use this method